# Cant call jQuery POST request from Javascript's addEventListener method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript file that handles a button click on my html page. It works well and detects the button tap, however I can't make the `POST` request work inside the addEventListener method. I get no errors in the console of my browser, it just simply doesn't work. My question is that what is missing? Based on the `POST` requests I checked this implementation should work fine.

// my .js file:

```
(function(){
const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
const txtEmail= document.getElementById('txtEmail');

btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {

    const email = txtEmail.value;
    console.log('test log');

    if (email.length < 4) {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: "/signup/",
          data: JSON.stringify({title: email}),
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.title);
          },
          dataType: "json"
        });
    }
});
}());
```

Comment: I don't see `txtEmail` defined.  Also take out the `alert('test alert msg')`.  You have it inside your ajax parameters and that's a syntax error.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery you might as well use it to wait until DOM is loaded (`ready()` method) and for all event handling.

Comment: @Thanks Taplar! The `txtEmail` was mistakenly removed.

Comment: @Sébastien Sorry I'm not really familiar with DOM related things. What does exactly means `you might as well use it to wait until DOM is loaded`? You mean the full page is loaded?

Comment: When your function runs you immediately  try to access elements from the page. However they may not have been loaded in memory at that time. It depends on the context of your code, just check https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the alert call from your object, that’s a syntax error, thus your snippet will not run because of that.

Also, unsure if this will make a difference but you could either replace the self executing function (IIFE) with jquery onload function, both provide an encapsulated scope... example below

```
(function () {

//...

})();
```

Becomes

```
$(function () {

//...

});
```

Where

```
//...
```

Is your code.

I would also add an error field to your jquery Ajax call, that way you can log any error.

```
error: function (err) {

    console.log(err);

}
```

That’s about all I can advise, given you have a syntax error in your question.

Become friends with the browser development tools, specifically the console and network tabs, console tab would pick up your syntax error, and network tab will yield the answers you’re looking for, when asking “is the endpoint being hit”, and “what response is the endpoint giving”.

Lastly, I’d add any else statement, after your if, which checks for the length of the email, a simple log will do, could be that you’re fetching the wrong email field, or it isn’t long enough.

Comment: Thanks! I have removed the alert and also added the error log, which logged an internal server error. It can't be a problem that I'm using it in the `addEventListener` method?

Comment: I already tried it without the if statement, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Nope, if the response is an internal server error, then the problem lays within your backend code, specifically the code which handles the POST request. That my friend, is outside of he scope of this question sadly, 100% has nothing to do with your addEventListener code, the fact that it returns a server error is proof that your code does request the server as expected, what’s going on in your POST route is anyone’s guess, perhaps add a new question with the relevant snippets (if your backend code)

Comment: That helped a lot! I was sure that my server code is proper. Thanks Lee!

Comment: No problem at all.